# Arch linux. Некорректная работа Xorg и LightDM

Tags: linux, archlinux, xorg, gentoo, lightdm

Доброго всем времени суток.

Имеется ноутбук `Lenovo B50-30` на который было решено установить `Arch Linux`.

Ноутбук использует две видеокарты, а именно интегрированную `Intel HD Graphics` и дискретную `Nvidia GTX 820m`.

С установкой самого дистрибутива не возникало никаких проблем как и не возникало их при установке нужных мне пакетов. После установки системы было решено установить `xfce4`, в чем так же не возникло никаких проблем.

На практически "голой" системе с `xfce4` никаких проблем не наблюдалось, `Nvidia 820m` работала на свободном, но маломощном драйвере `nouveau` - с ним система работала отлично.

Подошел момент установки драйверов видеоадаптера `nvidia`, так как карта `820m` считается устаревшей, то её драйверов нет в репозиториях `ArchLinux`. Установка была произведена из `AUR`, был выбран драйвер `nvidia-390xx` со всеми вытекающими зависимостями.

Всё вроде бы успешно, при выводе информации о `VGA и 3D` видно, что `Nvidia 820m` переключилась на свой родной драйвер от `nvidia` вместо `noyveau`. После этого был использован пакет `nvidia-configx` для создания конфигурации `Xorg`.

И с этого момента начинаются проблемы.

Если систему не перезагружать, а выйти из сессии и попробовать снова зайти под своим пользователем, то на 2 - 3 секунды появляется черный экран и выкидывает на авторизацию/вход в аккаунт пользователя `linux`.

Если же зайти под под `root`, то всё работает (на первый взгляд).

Если же перезагрузить систему, что необходимо сделать после установки драйверов `nvidia`, то после инициализации и загрузки `grub` появляется черный экран на 5 - 10 секунд (на самом деле в этот момент пытается стартануть менеджер входа `Light Display Managar` - `lightdm`). После чего на дисплеи лишь надпись с ошибкой о том, что `lightdm` не смог запуститься.

`nvidia-configx` правильно генерирует конфигурацию `xorg.conf`. Думал, что Xorg не может запуститься из-за `nvidia`, но удаление драйверов не помогало.

Так же `nvidia-390xx` корректно накладывает патч на ядро.

В чем может быть ошибка и как запустить `Xorg | lightdm` на видеоадаптере `nvidia` ноутбука или же просто заставить `Xorg` работать через  `Intel HD Graphics`? Пытался изменить конфигурацию `Xorg.conf`, вместо `nvidia` указывал драйвер и карточку интел - это не помогло.

PS - прикрепил логи.

```html
[    22.143] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    22.143] Build Operating System: Linux Archlinux
[    22.143] Current Operating System: Linux serve 5.14.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun, 10 Oct 2021 00:48:26 +0000 x86_64
[    22.143] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=24a3f37c-2015-49e3-b678-f34997052d7c rw quiet loglevel=3 audit=0 i915.modeset=1
[    22.143] Build Date: 04 August 2021  08:13:54AM
[    22.143]  
[    22.143] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    22.143]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    22.143] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    22.144] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Oct 12 02:48:52 2021
[    22.233] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    22.233] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    22.316] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    22.316] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    22.316] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    22.316] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    22.317] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    22.317] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    22.317] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    22.317] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    22.317] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    22.317] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    22.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[    22.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/TTF".
[    22.357]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/TTF").
[    22.357] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[    22.357]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    22.357]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[    22.357]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[    22.357]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.357] (==) FontPath set to:
    
[    22.358] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    22.358] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    22.358] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    22.358]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    22.358]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    22.358]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    22.358]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    22.359] (++) using VT number 7

[    22.359] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    22.361] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    22.375] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    22.378] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    22.382] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0f31:17aa:3986 rev 14, Mem @ 0xa3000000/4194304, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00003050/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    22.382] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:1140:17aa:3812 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00002000/128
[    22.382] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    22.382] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    22.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
[    23.846] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    23.846]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.846]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    23.856] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.144  Wed Jun  2 23:02:00 UTC 2021
[    23.892] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card1
[    23.892]    loading driver: nvidia
[    23.892] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    23.892] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[    23.892] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[    23.893] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 3
[    23.893] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    23.893] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    23.893] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    23.893] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    23.893] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    23.939] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    23.995] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.995]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 2.99.917
[    23.995]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.995]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    23.996] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    23.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    24.099] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    24.099]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    24.099]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    24.108] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    24.111] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[    24.111] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.112] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    24.115] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    24.115] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.115] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    24.116] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    24.189] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    24.189]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.20.13
[    24.189]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    24.189]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    24.189] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    24.191] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    24.191] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.191] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    24.193] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    24.193] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.193] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    24.196] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    24.196] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    24.197] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    24.198] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.144  Wed Jun  2 23:05:01 UTC 2021
[    24.198] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    24.199] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    24.252] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20201103
[    24.252] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled from 2.99.917-916-g31486f40
[    24.293] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    24.294] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    24.294] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    24.294] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    24.294] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    24.295] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    24.295] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    24.295] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[    24.296] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[    24.296] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[    24.296] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    24.296] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[    24.296] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    24.297] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    24.297] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    24.297] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    24.297] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    24.297] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    24.297] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    24.297] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[    24.298] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    24.298] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    24.298] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    24.298] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    24.298] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    24.298] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    24.298] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    24.298] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    24.298] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    24.298] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    24.298] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    24.298] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    24.347] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Baytrail (gen7) backend
[    24.347] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    24.347] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse disabled
[    24.347] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    24.352] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    24.353] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    24.353] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    24.353] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    24.354] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    24.354] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 DRI3 enabled
[    24.354] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    24.354] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    24.354] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    24.354] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    24.355] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    24.355] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    24.356] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    24.356] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    24.356] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    24.357] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    24.357] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    24.357] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    24.358] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    24.358] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    24.358] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    24.359] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    24.359] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    24.359] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    24.360] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    24.360] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    24.360] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    24.360] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    24.361] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    24.361] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    24.361] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    24.361] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    24.362] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    24.362] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    24.362] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    24.362] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    24.386] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[    24.423] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    24.424] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[    25.187] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    25.187] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.187] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.187] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    25.188] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    25.239] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.239]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.2.0
[    25.240]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    25.240]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    25.240] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    25.240] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    25.240] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    25.241] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.315] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.316] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    25.318] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    25.340] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    25.340] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    25.340] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    25.340] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    25.471] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.472] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    25.474] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event4)
[    25.474] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.474] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.474] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    25.474] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    25.474] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    25.474] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.476] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.477] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    25.477] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
[    25.553] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input4/event4"
[    25.553] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    25.553] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    25.554] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    25.565] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.566] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    25.575] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    25.575] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.575] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    25.582] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[    25.582] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.583] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.583] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    25.583] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    25.583] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    25.583] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.594] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.595] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    25.597] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[    25.673] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3/event3"
[    25.673] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    25.673] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    25.674] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    25.687] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.688] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    25.696] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    25.696] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.697] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.697] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    25.697] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    25.697] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    25.697] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.707] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.707] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    25.709] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    25.766] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[    25.767] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    25.767] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    25.767] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    25.777] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.778] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    25.794] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech G602 (/dev/input/event6)
[    25.795] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    25.795] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.795] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.795] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech G602'
[    25.795] (**) Logitech G602: always reports core events
[    25.795] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    25.796] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.811] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    25.813] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: device is a pointer
[    25.813] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: device is a keyboard
[    25.816] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: device removed
[    25.860] (II) libinput: Logitech G602: needs a virtual subdevice
[    25.860] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:046D:C537.0002/0003:046D:402C.0003/input/input17/event6"
[    25.860] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech G602" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[    25.860] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    25.860] (**) Logitech G602: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    25.861] (**) Logitech G602: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    25.861] (**) Logitech G602: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    25.865] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    25.866] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: device is a pointer
[    25.866] (II) event6  - Logitech G602: device is a keyboard
[    25.870] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech G602 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    25.870] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.870] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.870] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    25.872] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC (/dev/input/event13)
[    25.872] (**) Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.872] (**) Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.872] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC'
[    25.872] (**) Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: always reports core events
[    25.872] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[    25.872] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.876] (II) event13 - Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.876] (II) event13 - Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: device is a keyboard
[    25.877] (II) event13 - Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: device removed
[    25.936] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.3/2-4.3:1.0/input/input24/event13"
[    25.936] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    25.936] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    25.936] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    25.941] (II) event13 - Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.941] (II) event13 - Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: device is a keyboard
[    25.943] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[    25.943] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.943] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    25.944] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[    25.944] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.944] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    25.946] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
[    25.946] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.946] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    25.948] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Ideapad extra buttons (/dev/input/event7)
[    25.948] (**) Ideapad extra buttons: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    25.948] (**) Ideapad extra buttons: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    25.948] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Ideapad extra buttons'
[    25.948] (**) Ideapad extra buttons: always reports core events
[    25.948] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    25.948] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    25.951] (II) event7  - Ideapad extra buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    25.951] (II) event7  - Ideapad extra buttons: device is a keyboard
[    25.951] (II) event7  - Ideapad extra buttons: device removed
[    26.004] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input18/event7"
[    26.004] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Ideapad extra buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    26.004] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    26.004] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    26.007] (II) event7  - Ideapad extra buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    26.007] (II) event7  - Ideapad extra buttons: device is a keyboard
[    26.008] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event5)
[    26.008] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    26.008] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    26.008] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    26.008] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    26.008] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    26.009] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    26.011] (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    26.011] (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    26.013] (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    26.041] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input5/event5"
[    26.041] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    26.041] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    26.041] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[    26.043] (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    26.044] (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    26.047] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event9)
[    26.047] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    26.047] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    26.047] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    26.047] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[    26.047] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    26.049] (II) event9  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    26.052] (II) event9  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[    26.052] (II) event9  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[    26.090] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input20/event9"
[    26.090] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 14)
[    26.092] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    26.092] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    26.092] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    26.092] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    26.094] (II) event9  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    26.097] (II) event9  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[    26.099] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    26.099] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    26.099] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    26.100] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event8)
[    26.100] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    26.100] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    26.124] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    26.124] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    26.124] (**) Logitech G602: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    26.124] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech G602'
[    26.124] (**) Logitech G602: always reports core events
[    26.124] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    26.125] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[    26.125] (II) libinput: Logitech G602: is a virtual subdevice
[   163.807] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

PS. если удалить конфиги Xorg, то графическое окружение запускается, но nvidia по прежнему не работает.

Comment: Ищите где-нибудь в логах текст ошибки (в районе `/var/log/Xorg*` `/var/log/lightdm/` или около того)

Comment: А `xorg.conf` наверное лучше удалить, всё должно работать автоматически и без него

Comment: Да, к сожалению сейчас нет возможности загрузиться с Arch и показать логи, но в логах лишь то, что  Xorg упал после загрузки nvidia.

Comment: В логах должна быть описана причина, почему конкретно Xorg решил упасть

Comment: @andreymal разве?  `nvidia-configx` как раз и служит для интеграции nvidia и xorg.

Comment: Xorg сам прекрасно интегрируется и без файла xorg.conf

Comment: Попробую удалить как загружусь с Arch, но пытался перезапускать без строчек о видеокарте, результат был тем же

Comment: Но логи всё равно поищите, скорее всего проблема не в наличии/отсутствии файла xorg.conf, а в чём-то более специфическом

Comment: Приложите к вопросу лог X сервера. Без

Comment: у меня на генту 765m видяха и я не ставлю каких то особых драйверов и не патчу ядро.  И nvidia-configx не запускаю. И все работает. или у меня свежая видяха?

Comment: @KoVadim хммм... А как вы установили nvidia-390xxx из pacman без патча ядра, если nvidia-390xxx устанавливают из AUR. Ко всему этому - на Gentoo свой репозиторий и нет pacman и AUR. Вы с таким же успехом могли сказать "открой окошко настройки nvidia из Arch которое разработано для Ubuntu".

Comment: PS - смог добавить логи. Ошибки в том, что не подхватывает драйвера, но при этом они установлены в системе.

Comment: Загружены ли модули ядра? `lsmod | grep nvidia`

Comment: @ZerxaFunaKaZerxa - я ставил обычные драйвера nvidia - я к этому веду. я не ставил особые драйвера.

Comment: *Подошел момент установки драйверов видеоадаптера nvidia* — судя по приведённой дальше информации, этот момент и стал фатальным. видимо, кто-то над вами жестоко подшутил, объявив о наступлении этого момента.

Comment: @andreymal ничего не выводит, к сожалению. Из интереса и с отвращением установил Ubuntu. на ней как оказалось те же самые проблемы с установкой драйверов, при том, что на другом ноутбуке и ПК никогда не возникало проблем с картами nvidia.

Comment: Хочу ещё добавить то, что даже под windows на данном ноутбуке имеются проблемы с графикой, а именно то, что никакие драйвера с офф. сайта не ставятся, необходимо скачивать драйвера с сайта Lenovo, либо обновлять их через центр обновлений windows.

Comment: @ZerxaFunaKaZerxa если lsmod ничего не выводит, значит нужно в первую очередь эту проблему и добиваться чтобы что-то вывелось. Если попробовать в лоб `sudo modprobe nvidia` что пишет?

Comment: @andreymal так же ничего не выводит

Comment: @andreymal я не знаю, что именно случилось, но переустанавливал систему около 7 - 8 раз, каждый раз пытался по новой установить все драйвера, ничего хорошего из этого не выходило. Ко всему этому у меня не добавлялся в черный список `nouveau`` и при выводе `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"` nvidia не загружала драйвер, а лишь показывала `kernal driver: nvidia, nouveau`.

Сейчас же решил снова посмотреть на вывод lspcu и увидел заветную строку: `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

Comment: @andreymal в общем то, принудительная загрузка модуля - `modprobe nvidia` помогает, x.org конечно не заработал на nvidia, но он и не должен. Единственная проблема осталась в том, что после перезагрузки я снова вижу у видеокарты `Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia` вместо `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`